# pycharm - cannot configure interpreter to run scratches

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I created a Django project in Pycharm using virtualenvwrapper. My python was located in `~/.virtualenvs/django_cpa`. Later I renamed my virtualenv to `pubscout`, and changed Python interpreter for Pycharm to `/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/pubscout/bin/python`. This works fine with files that are within the project:

[image]

However when I try to run a **scratch file** from within this project's environment, I get an error which indicates that Pycharm is still trying to use the old interpreter path for scratches:

[image]

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Goto Run/Debug Configurations
Defaults -> Python -> (on the right side) select correct *Python interpretter* , after that - all **Scratches will use your selected venv**

[image]

p.s. You may need to remove/setup correct venv for existing run-configurations for your previously executed python scratches